# convert from Control to Func<Control> for TabbedView - Devexpress Windows Form

Tags: c#, windows, forms, devexpress

I'm using Devexpress for a Windows Form app.
so I want to replace this snippet:

```
tabbedView.AddDocument(userControl);
tabbedView.ActivateDocument(userControl);
```

with this snippet:

```
tabbedView.AddOrActivateDocument(doc => doc.Caption == e.Element.Name, userControl);
```

the problem here is that this method requests a `Func<Control>` instead of `Control`.

I found the `Func<Object,Object>` documentation and specification but couldn't find how to convert from an `Object` to its `Func<Object>`.

I appreciate your help. Thank you.

Comment: `Func<Control>` means that it takes no parameter and returns a `Control`, something like `public Func<Control> getControl = () => new Control();`

Comment: you can fix this by passing a lambda expression. Try this `tabbedView.AddOrActivateDocument(doc => doc.Caption == e.Element.Name, () => userControl);`

Comment: Thank you sir! This solved my problem, but I don't understand this concept yet.

Comment: That's what I exactly did and solved my issue. Thank you so much.

Comment: let me add this as an answer. Hope you will accept it :)

Comment: and just a suggestion while posting such questions it is always good to attack a link to the docs. I was able to figure out the solution by actually reading the docs :)

Comment: may be accept the answer as well :|

Answer (score 1):

`Func<Control>` means that it takes no parameter and returns a Control, something like

```
public Func<Control> getControl = () => new Control();
```

You can fix this by passing a lambda expression. Try this

```
tabbedView.AddOrActivateDocument(doc => doc.Caption == e.Element.Name, () => userControl);
```